# Remove last delimeter from a .TXT file in Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have an S3 file generated from the different system which is as below:

```
A1|~|B1|~|C1|~|D1|~|

A2|~|B2|~|C2|~|D2|~|

A3|~|B3|~|C3|~|D3|~|

A4|~|B4|~|C4|~|D4|~|
```

Now while reading this file in AWS Glue Pyspark script, I want to remove the last delimiter from the file. Could you please let me know how to do it?

Issue is-
While trying to convert this .TXT file to parquet, when I am mentioning delimeter as '|~|' it's adding an extra column at the end. This is happening because in the source file there is an extra |~| delimeter at the end of each row.

So that's why I want to remove the last |~| delimeter from each row in the file and then convert it to parquet.

code :-

```
input = sc.textFile("filename.TXT").map(lambda x: x.split('|~|')) 
df=spark.createDataFrame(input,list_of_colun_names)
```

Comment: can you post your code like what have you tried?

Comment: input = sc.textFile("filename.TXT").map(lambda x: x.split('|~|'))
df=spark.createDataFrame(input,list_of_colun_names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to remove the last element of the array created by your lambda function.

So you could change your lambda function to something like this.

```py
input = sc.textFile("filename.TXT").map(lambda x: x.split('|~|')[:-1])
```